# T-SQL to group results by a range of possible values

Tags: group-by, tsqlt

Not sure how to word the question:

I have a query such as

```
SELECT s.*
FROM SUMMARY s
WHERE s.TYP = 'A'
AND s.NUM > 0
AND s.NUM <= 999999
```

and a group by like

```
SELECT s.TYP, s.COUNT(TYPE)
FROM SUMMARY s
GROUP BY s.TPY
```

which gives:

```
A 38720
B 39500
C 170
D 850
E 8891
```

What I'd like to do is get a "split" of my results using a "range" like:

```
TYP RANGE(NUM) COUNT
  A 0000>1000  240
  A 1000>2000  800
  A 2000>3000  120
etc...
```

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at IF in the SELECT command to group by ranges you have in the rows and then [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) fction to flip the result.

Comment: Do you mean to use CASE in the SELECT?  I can't see how to get that into a result set that can be PIVOTed?

Comment: yes, CASE. So you first create a table with columns Range0To100,Range100To200 etc which will have for each row just one value. From this table, you create another table which will sum up the columns from the previous table and then you flip over using PIVOT. All can be done in one SQL using select xx from (select xxx ) t.